# Copy properties and add year to date properties

Tags: java, date, copy

I need to copy an object and add a year to each of the date of the same

So first of all i will get the original object and copy it with this method:

```
Foo copyFoo (Foo foo){
  Foo f = new Foo();
  //for all properties in FOo
  f.set(foo.get());
  return f;
}
```

And then add a year to every property of the type Date of the object:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(randomDate);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, n);
newDate = c.getTime();
```

Is there any way to get all the date type properties of an object without needing to go one by one?

Comment: It sounds like you will want to look into reflection (look it up).

Comment: The classes `Date` and `Calendar` are both long outdated and poorly designed. Do yourself the favour of finding the appropriate class from [java.time, the modern java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for your properties (perhaps `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime`). Then use `yourDateProperty.plusYears(1)` for adding a year.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-class-fields-with-specified-data-type/ @OleV.V. thanks i will check this web look like i need